# Check to see if SaveAs dialogue box appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Is it possible to check to see if a SaveAs dialogue box appears in javascript/jquery? I want to see if it appears so that i can remove a loading gif. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is not possible. You don't have any control over the browser or it's interface with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to check for the existence of a browser modal dialog. Even if it was, script execution is completely halted until the dialog is dealt with, so you wouldn't be able to do anything in the background while the 'Save As...' dialog was visible anyway.